# Python and Tar command shell=True

Tags: python, tar, popen

I wrote this script to tar some backups :

```
date = str(now.year)+str(now.month)+str(now.day)
tar="tar -pczf "+date+"backup_lucas.tar.gz /home/lucas/backup/"
subprocess.Popen(tar)
```

But then I get :

```
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(tar)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I add add shell=True to the Popen command it works :

```
subprocess.Popen(tar,shell=True)
```

However I heard the shell=True is to be avoided as it is insecure sometimes (?).

How can I successfully issue the command without using shell=True ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When shell=False you need to pass your command via a list:

```
date = str(now.year)+str(now.month)+str(now.day)
filename = date + "backup_lucas.tar.gz"
subprocess.Popen(['tar', '-pczf', filename, '/home/lucas/backup/'])
```

Edit: the important part from the docs:

"On Unix, with shell=False (default): In this case, the Popen class uses os.execvp() to execute the child program. args should normally be a sequence. If a string is specified for args, it will be used as the name or path of the program to execute; this will only work if the program is being given no arguments." - http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Answer (score 2):

@sgallen has the fundamentally correct answer. However as an additional note: you may also find it useful to specify the absolute path to your "tar" command, e.g. `subprocess.Popen(['/usr/sbin/tar', ...]`. Where that resides is, of course, specific to your Linux flavor.